# $2\times 2$ matrix similar to a matrix of its eigenvalues' real and imaginary parts

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix with the complex eigenvalues $\lambda = \alpha \pm i \beta$.

I need to show that $A = V \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ - \beta & \alpha \end{pmatrix}V^{-1}$, where $V$ is an invertible matrix with columns $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$. Then, I need to show that $v_{1}+iv_{2}$ is an eigenvector of $\lambda = \alpha + i\beta$.

First of all, this is for a differential equations course, and it has been a very long time since I've done any serious linear algebra. I think what this problem is saying is that I need to show that $A$ is similar to a matrix with entries the $\pm$ real and imaginary parts of its eigenvalues, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Secondly, how do I show that $v_{1}+iv_{2}$ is an eigenvalue of the $\alpha + i\beta$ eigenvalue without explicitly knowing what $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ are? (Or will I know? I'm very confused).

I am in a bit over my head with this problem and could really use some guidance. I thank you for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $\beta\ne 0$, otherwise we’re dealing with a repeated real eigenvalue, which requires a different analysis. A $2\times2$ matrix with eigenvalues $\alpha\pm i\beta$ has characteristic equation $(\lambda-\alpha)^2+\beta^2=0$. Let $B=A-\alpha I$. By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $(A-\alpha I)^2+\beta^2I=0$, therefore $B^2=-\beta^2I$. Let $\mathbf v_1$ be any nonzero real vector and define $\mathbf v_2 = -\frac1\beta B\mathbf v_1$. Then $$B\mathbf v_2 = \frac1\beta B^2\mathbf v_1 = \beta\mathbf v_1$$ and by definition $$B\mathbf v_1=-\beta\mathbf v_2.$$ Let $V = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf v_1&\mathbf v_2\end{bmatrix}$. Then $$BV\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} = B\mathbf v_1 = -\beta\mathbf v_2 = -\beta V\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$BV\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix} = B\mathbf v_2 = \beta\mathbf v_1 = \beta V\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$ therefore $$BV = V\begin{bmatrix}0&\beta\\ -\beta&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ Finally, $$A = \alpha I+B = \alpha I+V\begin{bmatrix}0&\beta\\-\beta&0\end{bmatrix}V^{-1} = V\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\-\beta&\alpha\end{bmatrix}V^{-1}.$$

Proving the second part is a matter of multiplying out $A(\mathbf v_1+i\mathbf v_2) = (\alpha I+B)(\mathbf v_1+i\mathbf v_2)$ for this choice of $\mathbf v_1$ and $\mathbf v_2$ and doing a bit of straightforward algebra.

Comment: might be a silly thing to ask, but we know that $V$ is invertible because?

Comment: @ALannister It’s a fair question. $\mathbf v_1$ and $\mathbf v_2$ are linearly independent because $A$, and so also $B$, has no real eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2):

Your result stands only if $(*)$ $\beta\not= 0$. We assume $(*)$ and that $A\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ with $spectrum(A)=\{\alpha \pm i\beta\}$. Since $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$, then it is similar over $\mathbb{C}$ to $diag(\lambda,\overline{\lambda})$ and then, to $B=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\-\beta&\alpha\end{pmatrix}$ (since $spectrum(B)=spectrum(A))$. Since $(1)$ two real matrices that are similar over $\mathbb{C}$ are also similar over $\mathbb{R}$, there is an invertible $V\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $A=VBV^{-1}$.

EDIT.  The proof of $(1)$ is standard. Let $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{R}),P=P_1+iP_2\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be s.t. $A=PBP^{-1}$. Then $AP=PB$ and moreover $AP_1=P_1B,AP_2=P_2B$; then, for every $t\in\mathbb{C}$, $A(P_1+tP_2)=(P_1+tP_2)B$. Consider the function $f:t\in \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \det(P_1+tP_2)$; $f$ is a polynomial that is not identically $0$ because $f(i)\not= 0$; then there is $t\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(t)\not= 0$ and we are done.

Comment: is there any way to show this without using this result? Or perhaps you could point me to somewhere where I could find said result in its entirety?

Comment: If you are OK with the fact that $A$ and $B$ can be diagonalized, then, it is obvious that they are similar to the same diagonal matrices since they share the same eigenvalues. Since similarity is an equivalence relation, it is transitive, thus, $A$ and $B$ are similar which is what you are asked.

Comment: @ Bill O'Haran , by your reasoning $A=VBV^{-1}$ where $V$ is complex because the eigenvalues are not in $\mathbb{R}$; in fact, we can choose a real matrix $V$. cf. my edit.

Comment: @loupblanc which edit are you referring to?

Comment: @BillO'Haran I thought matrices with complex eigenvalues could not be diagonalized.

Comment: @BillO'Haran , just now.

Comment: @loupblanc possibly a stupid question, but how do you know that there even exists a $P=P_{1}+i P_{2} \in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ s.t. $A=PBP^{-1}$?

Comment: @loupblanc , I agree but I fail to see the need to solve into $\mathbb{R}$ (even $v_1 + i v_2$ being an eigenvector does not prevent $V$ from being complex).

Comment: @ALannister , as long as $\beta \neq 0$, the two eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct hence, the characteristic polynomial only has simple roots and $A$ can thus be diagonalized.

Comment: @BillO'Haran can you answer the last follow-up question that I directed at the White Wolf (aka the King in the North)?

Comment: @ALannister ,sure, $P$ verifies the definition of similarity between $A$ and $B$ and since $P$ is complex, it can be separated into its real ($P_1$) and imaginary ($P_2$) parts like any complex matrix. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

As loup blanc noticed, your assertions hold only if $\beta \neq 0$. Then you are able to prove $A = V \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ - \beta & \alpha \end{pmatrix}V^{-1}$ by using the spectrum of $A$.

For your second question, let $V=\begin{pmatrix} v_{11} & v_{12} \\ v_{21} & v_{22} \end{pmatrix}$ and look at $AV = V \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ - \beta & \alpha \end{pmatrix}$ column by column since $V= (v_1, v_2)$:
$$
Av_1=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha v_{11} - \beta v_{12} \\ \alpha v_{21} - \beta v_{22} \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
Av_2=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha v_{12} + \beta v_{11} \\ \alpha v_{22} + \beta v_{21} \end{pmatrix}
$$

Then, $Av_1 + i Av_2 = \lambda (v_1+iv_2)$

Comment: if $\beta=0$, then it degenerates into the case where we have a real, repeated eigenvalue. What would we do in that case?

Comment: Well, to be able to diagonalize $A$, you would have to prove that $\text{Ker}(A-\lambda I)$ has dimension 2. Otherwise, $A$ is trigonalizable (as any complex matrix) but not diagonalizable.

Comment: is that something we can do if we don't know explicitly what $A$ is?

Comment: I guess the easiest way would be to check that the rank of $A-\lambda I$ is 0. But other than that, I do not think it is something one can do without further knowledge of $A$. Maybe someone more knowledgeable than me will find some way.

Comment: can you check if rank of $A-\lambda i=0$ without knowing what $A$ is in this case?

Comment: The only matrix of rank $0$ is the matrix with all entries set to $0$ so the only case where $\beta = 0$ and $A$ is diagonalizable is when $A$ is already diagonal. Basically, the only case where $A$ is not diagonalizable is when $\text{det}A= 0$ and $A\neq 0$ and $A$ is not diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \\ 1 & -i \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} A & -B \\ B & A \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \frac12 & \frac12 \\-\frac i2& \frac i2\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} A+Bi &\\ &A-Bi \end{pmatrix}
$$