# Finding an invertible matrix P and some matrix C

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse

Find an invertible matrix $P$ and a matrix $C$ of the form

$C=\begin{pmatrix}a & -b\\b & a\end{pmatrix}$

such that the given matrix $A$ has the form $A = PCP^{-1}$

$A=\begin{pmatrix}5 & -2\\1 & 3\end{pmatrix}$

The first thing i tried to do was to find the eigenvectors of matrix $A$ and i got these vectors (which i glued together to get matrix $P$ and  $P^{-1}$)

$P=\begin{pmatrix}1+ i& 1-i\\1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

$P^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2i} & \frac{-1+i}{2i}\\-\frac{1}{2i} & \frac{1+i}{2i}\end{pmatrix}$

Im not sure how to find the matrix $C$, i thought at first i could plug in the eigenvalues in the $C$ matrix, but i don't think that is what they problem i asking me to do.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$2\times 2$ matrix similar to a matrix of its eigenvalues' real and imaginary parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2739392/2-times-2-matrix-similar-to-a-matrix-of-its-eigenvalues-real-and-imaginary-pa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find $P$ and $C$, note that

$$A = PCP^{-1}\iff AP=PC$$

since A and C are similar we have that

- $Tr(A)=Tr(C) \implies 2a=8 \implies a=4$
- $\det(A)=\det(C) \implies a^2+b^2=17 \implies b=\pm1$

then let $P=[v_1\, v_2]$ and we have

- $Av_1=av_1+bv_2$
- $Av_2=-bv_1+av_2$

and with $v_1=(x,y)\quad v_2=(z,w)$ we have for $b=1$

- $5x-2y=4x+z\implies x-2y-z=0$
- $x+3y=4y+w\implies x-y-w=0$
- $5z-2w=-x+4z\implies x+z-2w=0$
- $z+3w=-y+4w\implies y+z-w=0$

and we find $v_1=(2,1)\, v_2=(0,1)$ and finally

$$C=\begin{pmatrix}4 & -1\\1 & 4\end{pmatrix}\quad P=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0\\1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\quad P^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac12 & 0\\-\frac12 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Shouldn’t that be $AP=PC$?

Comment: @amd Oh yes of course! The system should be indeed coherent with this assumption. I fix the typo, Thanks!

Comment: @amd I've used a brute force direct method with an ugly determinant that I've solved by wolfram. Is there some more elegant or effective way?

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ has two complex roots: $\lambda_1 = a + ib$ and $\lambda_2 = a - ib$.

Since, $A$  and $C$ share the same eigenvalues (in dimension 2 it is equivalent to checking that the determinant and trace of both matrices are equal), they are similar and such a matrix $P$ exists.

If $b=0$ ($\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda$), existence of $P$ is not guaranteed unless you can show that $\text{Ker}(A-\lambda I)$ has dimension 2.

So, in a nutshell, you have to find the eigenvalues of $A$ and take the real and imaginary parts to get the entries of $C$.

Comment: I'm guessing from your answer that you found out for yourself :)

Comment: I already knew that every $2\times2$ matrix with complex eigenvalues is similar to a conformal matrix. What I should’ve written is that this answer is incomplete. You’ve explained what $C$ should be, but not how to find an appropriate $P$.

Comment: You are quite right. I assumed - out of laziness, I must say - that once $C$ is found, finding $P$ is quite straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Per [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2739392/265466), $A$ has eigenvalues $4\pm i$, so it is similar to a matrix of the form $$C=\begin{bmatrix}4&-1\\1&4\end{bmatrix}.$$ [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2740736/265466) shows how to construct an appropriate basis without computing any eigenvalues explicitly. Note that the resulting matrix in the question has the opposite signs from what we want on the $\beta$’s in our matrix, but we can flip the signs by taking $\mathbf v_2=\frac1\beta B\mathbf v_1$.

Following this method, we have $$B = \begin{bmatrix}5&-2\\1&3\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}4&0\\0&4\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&-2\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$ Taking $\mathbf v_1=(1,0)^T$, we have $\mathbf v_2=(1,1)^T$, therefore $$P = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}, P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Since you’ve gone to the trouble of finding eigenvectors of $A$, the second part of the linked question suggests another way to find $P$. Since $A$ is real, then for any complex vector $\mathbf v$, $$A(\Re\mathbf v) = \frac12A(\mathbf v+\bar{\mathbf v}) = \frac12(A\mathbf v+A\bar{\mathbf v}) = \frac12(A\mathbf v+\overline{A\mathbf v}) = \Re(A\mathbf v)$$ and similarly $A(\Im\mathbf v)=\Im(A\mathbf v)$. Let $\mathbf v_r$ and $\mathbf v_i$ be linearly independent real vectors such that $\mathbf v_r+i\mathbf v_i$ is an eigenvector of $\alpha-i\beta$. (Proving that this is always possible is a relatively simple, but useful exercise.) Then $$A\mathbf v_r = \Re[(\alpha-i\beta)(\mathbf v_r+i\mathbf v_i)] = \alpha\mathbf v_r+\beta\mathbf v_i$$ and $$A\mathbf v_i = \Im[(\alpha-i\beta)(\mathbf v_r+i\mathbf v_i)] = \alpha\mathbf v_i-\beta\mathbf v_r.$$ Setting $P=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf v_r&\mathbf v_i\end{bmatrix}$ and $J=\small{\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}}$, we can write these as $$\begin{align}A\mathbf v_r &= P(\alpha I+\beta J)P^{-1}\mathbf v_r \\ A\mathbf v_i &= P(\alpha I+\beta J)P^{-1}\mathbf v_i\end{align}$$ and since $\mathbf v_r$ and $\mathbf v_i$ are linearly independent, this holds for all $\mathbf v$, therefore $A=P(\alpha I+\beta J)P^{-1}$. Note that this is consistent with the first method since from the expression for $A\mathbf v_r$ we obtain $\mathbf v_i = \frac1\beta(A-\alpha I)\mathbf v_r$.

For your matrix, you’ve found that $(1-i,1)^T$ is an eigenvector of $4-i$. This splits into real and imaginary parts $(1,1)^T$ and $(-1,0)^T$, respectively, which gives $P=\small{\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}}$.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't use the similaraty condition at first!