# Diagonalize matrix with complex eigenvalues by real basis

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to diagonalize the following matrix with complex eigenvalues by real basis, but I'm not quite sure how to deal with it. Please give me some advice, thanks for help!

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 & 0 & 4 \\ 1 & 0 & -4 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: How can a real matrix times a real vector possibly equal a non-real complex number times a real vector?

Comment: @ancientmathematician   there is a relevant example on the first page of https://people.math.osu.edu/costin.10/5101/Eigenvalues%20p20-30.pdf  It seems this is called the real Canonical Form or the Real Jordan form. I did one yesterday that had all genuine eigenvalues https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2742114/matrix-in-canonical-form-of-an-orthogonal-transformation/2743574#2743574   This question is similar but needs that business about generalized eigenvectors. On the other hand, the final answer is all nice numbers

Comment: Thanks, @WillJagy I was just objecting to a real "diagonalization" which isn't on.

Answer (score 1):

I finished this, I think I will revise it to agree with the example in Costin, which is the only image i could find so far that showed what I wanted. First we find the Jordan form with the complex eigenvalues; this involves generalized eigenvectors here. Next, for the two vectors for a fixed eigenvalue (here $i$) for each make a pair of real vectors out of the real and imaginary parts. Just needs care. I need to get groceries and will typeset things later, that will take some real time. Notes at [COSTIN](https://people.math.osu.edu/costin.10/5101/Eigenvalues%20p20-30.pdf)

[image]

Here is the Jordan form $J$ and how to get there as $P^{-1}A P = J$

$$
\frac{1}{8}
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1&i&0&0 \\
0&0&-4i&4 \\
-i&-1&0&0 \\
0&0&4&-4i \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
0&-1&0&4 \\
1&0&-4&0 \\
0&0&0&-1 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
4&0&4i&0 \\
-4i&0&-4&0 \\
0&i&0&1 \\
0&1&0&i \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
i&1&0&0 \\
0&i&0&0 \\
0&0&-i&1 \\
0&0&0&-i \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Give me a bit more time, real part next. All we do is take the real and imaginary parts of the (generalized) eigenvectors that gave eigenvalue $i$ in getting $J,$ these being the first two columns on the left.

$$
\frac{1}{4}
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&-1&0&0 \\
0&0&0&4 \\
0&0&4&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
0&-1&0&4 \\
1&0&-4&0 \\
0&0&0&-1 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
4&0&0&0 \\
0&-4&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
0&1&1&0 \\
-1&0&0&1 \\
0&0&0&1 \\
0&0&-1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$